# updating ebgaramond package on arch linux

Tags: texlive-2019, garamond

A couple of months ago there was an update of the ebgaramond package. The update is not yet included in texlive-fontsextra, which is the package you'd normally install on arch linux to get the garamond fonts. So I tried to install it locally, via tllocalmgr (tlmgr is currently broken on arch). I then get the message that there is conflict between the package and texlive-fontsextra. It gives me the option to install the updated package and uninstall texlive-fontsextra. If I do that, however, I'm unable to compile a document with the ebgaramond fonts at all. In short, I'm unable to install the updated package. Does someone know of another way in which I may be able to install the update?

Comment: You can try to install manually, `ebgaramond` provides a TDS archive with installation instructions in the README file (see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond).

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's what I ended up doing. I had hoped there was an easier way. (At least on arch it's a bit of a hassle -- the maps are all over the place.)